# UDFs in Excel add-ins only work when I open the add-in first. How do I get Excel to link the add-in to the spread sheet naturally?

Tags: excel, vba, user-defined-functions, add-in

I'm using Excel in Microsoft 365 and I have several UDFs written in MS VBA and saved in a *.xla file located in C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\AddIns.  Additionally, this file has been successfully loaded as an add-in because I can see it in the Add-ins window made available on the Developer tab's "Excel Add-ins" icon.  I can also view the code in the module from the Visual Basic window.

The problem is all instances of a UDF have the following error:  #NAME?.

However, if I open the *.xla file first (which results in a completely blank spreadsheet i.e, no cells) and then open a saved spreadsheet containing my UDFs, all of the UDFs work fine.  While this is a workaround, it is a bit clumsy and I would like a cleaner solution.

My expectation was because my *.xla file was loaded as an Excel Add-in it would naturally be available to use in any Excel spreadsheet.

I also tried unchecking the Add-in I created when the spreadsheet was open but when I re-opened the spreadsheet, each instance of a UDF is altered with the path to the *.xla file mentioned above.  New instances of a UDF will not work unless I enter the full path.  For example:
='C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\AddIns\myAddIn.xla'!UDFname(E9,E10).

Comment: is the add-in enabled?

Comment: Thanks for the question.  The add-in is enabled.  When viewing the Add-ins window, I have the box checked for my add-in along with other built-in add ins such as solver.  Those built-in add-ins work perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

I was curious about this issue and went back to the website of the late but great  [Chip Pearson](http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/CreateAddIn.aspx). Following the instructions from his page, I was able to accomplish what you are stuck on. Looking at your question (well done btw), it does look like you've saved it to the proper location, but i would triple check as that seems most probable for an error.

For what it's worth, here's what I was able to do to get a UDF to appear as a recognized formula from an initial load blank file:

- Downloaded [Chip's test file](http://www.cpearson.com/Zips/TestAddIn.zip) and extracted the zip
- Within Excel → developer tab → Excel Add-ons (NOT COM!) → [Click on browse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BMcW3.png)
- Whatever folder opens is where the `xla` should be, so I copied Chip's file there
- I closed and reopened Excel, then reviewed the code in the module, which does not have any UDF's an it, so I added a formula `thanksPearson` and hit save. The entire code from the module is saved below from the `xla`.
- I saved, closed Excel, then reopened and the formula `=thanksPerason("boom")` performed as expected.

[image]

```
Option Explicit

Sub MacroToRunOne()
    Dim S As String
    S = "Hello World From One:" & vbCrLf & _
        "This Add-In File Name: " & ThisWorkbook.FullName
    MsgBox S
End Sub

Function thanksPerason(anINput As Variant) As String
    thanksPerason = " what the function is this" & anINput
End Function


Sub MacroToRunTwo()
    Dim S As String
    S = "Hello World From Two:" & vbCrLf & _
        "This Add-In File Name: " & ThisWorkbook.FullName
    MsgBox S
End Sub
```

#### Remember Pearson

In case it's not obvious, I'm a fan of the work of Chip Pearson [who died way too early](https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/if-chip-pearsons-website-ever-helped-you-please-jot-a-note.1054437/) in 2018 due to a car accident. If you read through his website, it is absolutely a masterpiece of well-written comprehensible explanations with examples that are [hailed as immeasurably more useful](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/367383/can-we-preserve-chip-pearsons-content-on-stack-overflow) than anything Microsoft ever produced. Anyway. Just a guy worth giving a shout-out to every now and then considering the amount of value he delivered to the world.

Comment: Thanks for the lead to Mr. Pearson's site!Chip's website is being blocked by our admins, but when I use my own *.xla and following your instructions it works perfectly the first time, but if I re-open the file, all calls to UDFs are prepended with the path to the *.xla file as in:

='C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\AddIns\myNewAddIn.xla'!UDFname(E9,E10)

I renamed the add-in to get a fresh start.

For now I'll open the needed *.xla files first.

Comment: My best guess is the admins are doing more than blocking good old Chip's site! `3:1` says it works on your own personal device.